# Where to store preferences, Log files, Caches on Mac OS X for Java apps

Tags: java, macos, directory, settings, preferences

Where should  preference files, log files, caches files, database files, go on Mac OS X and how to get those locations from Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As per java-dev@lists.apple.com list [by Mike Swingler](https://lists.apple.com/archives/java-dev/2019/Jan/msg00000.html)

Preferences is explained here: [Technical Q&A QA1170 Important Java Directories on Mac OS](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1170/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10001702)

Logs should probably go into System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/Logs/" + "your.app.identifier".

Caches should either go in the directory returned from System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), or System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/Caches/" + "your.app.identifier".

Database files, autosave information, and other things that represent user data that could be lost if deleted should go into System.getProperty("user.home") + "/Library/Application Support/" + "Your App Name".

To request a new tech note, or update the existing QA1170 with this information, please file a request at http://bugreporter.apple.com